# How to make md-contact-chips readonly to true

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

The [md-chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdChips) has **readonly** attribute that disables list manipulation (deleting or adding list items), hiding the input and delete buttons. If no ng-model is provided, the chips will automatically be marked as readonly.

But the [md-contacts-chips](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdContactChips) have no **readonly** attribute.

How am I able to disable the remove button for the chips?

Comment: can you disable it ?

Comment: I don't know the best approach

Answer (score 5):

I use kind of workaround for this.

You can add `ng-class` to `md-chips` like that:

```
<md-contact-chips ng-class="{'readonly': ctrl.readonly}"
```

In the controller set `readonly` variable as You need and add style for `.readonly` class. In my case it is:

```
md-chips-wrap {
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: default;

  button.md-chip-remove {
    display: none;
  }

  .md-chip-input-container md-autocomplete {
    display: none;
    cursor: default;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have create a new "chips-contacts", but list my custom contacts, with readonly

```
<md-chips ng-model="asyncContacts" class="md-contact-chips" md-removable="false" readonly="true">
<md-chip-template>
    <div class="md-contact-avatar">
        <img ng-src="{{$chip.image}}" class="list-product-chip-image" alt="{{$chip.name}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="md-contact-name">
        [{{$index}}] {{$chip.name}}
        ({{$chip.amount}})
    </div>
</md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```